# font awesome relative file path not found in Prod build

Tags: html, css, angular, font-awesome, scss-mixins

font-awesome not loading in prod build but its loading in localhost.

I am using below code

**_Variable.scss**:

```
 $fa-font-path: "../webfonts" !default;
```

**solid.scss:**

```
@import "variables";

@font-face {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-display: $fa-font-display;
  src: url("#{$fa-font-path}/fa-solid-900.eot");
  src: url("#{$fa-font-path}/fa-solid-900.eot?#iefix")
      format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("#{$fa-font-path}/fa-solid-900.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("#{$fa-font-path}/fa-solid-900.woff") format("woff"),
    url("#{$fa-font-path}/fa-solid-900.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("#{$fa-font-path}/fa-solid-900.svg#fontawesome") format("svg");
}
```

I build my angular project and ran index.html. *Font awesome icons are not loading. Its looking in C:/ drive folder instead of my project build folder*?
[image]

**angular.json file:**

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:build",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/registrationApp",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/webfonts",
              "src/assets",
              "src/config.json",
              "src/config.local.json"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": ["./src/styles", "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss"]
            },
```

Please suggest what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In `angular.json` file,

find build object and add `webfonts` folder in it

like

```
"build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "build",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "assets": [
             "src/webfonts"
        ]
}
```

what it will do, is it will create a `assets` folder in your build, and add `webfonts` folder in assets.

Comment: I added "src/webfonts". wefonts folder not created in build folder?

Comment: can you post your `angular.json` file?.... Also make sure webfonts folder is present in src folder

Comment: I update code with my angular json file. and there is no webfonts folder in my angular project

Comment: then what is this?  `../webfonts`, I am guessing this is a folder and you have given relative path. So what you have to do keep a copy of folder in src folder, so that while building angular cli can add  it in `assets`

Answer (score 0):

Place your fonts inside assets folder and give relative path to refer it, so that while building webpack will completely copy the asset file and modifies it's related paths...

Instead of this, I do recommend you to use some cdn which is deployed in cloud - which will be easier to browser for cache it.